# Export Files Taking Too much Time Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport

I have installed magento 1.9.2.3. When i am going to export our order as csv its taking too much time and request time out error.

I also increase the limit of following options:

```
max_execution_time = 18000
max_input_time = 6000
max_input_vars = 10000
memory_limit = 1024M
```

but it still not export the file.

when i search the order number and try to export it than it export the file.

can someone let me know what is the issue?

Comment: Did you re-index and clear cache after changes ?

Comment: i just clear the cache but not re-index. let me re-index all

Comment: if any change not appear see the log file in `var/log`  and tell me about result. **Note**: make sure to enable `system log`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update existing products by csv import than include only those column which you want to update with SKU. yes, sku has required column then you can include columns which are going to update the product attributes. It imports products so fast!!!!